# Как правильно создать emun строк и проверить вхождение в него?

Tags: typescript

С `API` я получаю имена статусов. Из них спомощью фабрики формирую экземпляры статусов на фронте. С `API` приходит строка. Чтобы дальше по коду не было ошибок и была типизация создаю `enum` имён статусов:

```js
export enum STATUSES_NAMES {
  CREATED = 'Создано',
  DELETED = 'Удалено',

  // Очень много имён статусов
}
```

Фабрика создающая экземпляры статусов:

```js
// Импорты

export default class FactoryStatuses {
  public static createByName(name: STATUSES_NAMES): IStatus {
    const parameters = {
      name,
    };

    return FactoryStatuses._create(parameters);
  }

  public static createFromDB(parameters: IConstructorParameters): IStatus {
    const _parameters = {
      name: parameters.name,
    };

    return FactoryStatuses._create(_parameters);
  }

  private static _create(parameters: IConstructorParameters): IStatus {
    if (!FactoryStatuses._existsName(parameters.name)) {
      throw new Error('Status name dose not exist');
    }

    return new Status(parameters);
  }

  private static _existsName(name: string): boolean {
    return Object.values(STATUSES_NAMES).includes(name);
  }
}
```

Интерфейсы:

```js
export interface IStatus {
  name: STATUSES_NAMES;
}

export interface IConstructorParameters {
  name: string;
}
```

В методе `existsName` получаю ошибку типов:

> TS2345: Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'STATUSES_NAMES'.

Как обойти это проблему или правильно создать `enum`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `function isNumber(x: any): x is number`
  https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards
- `assert(condition: any, msg?: string): asserts condition` https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions

### 1

`// @ts-ignore`

### 2

`name as any` || `name as STATUSES_NAMES`

### 3

[песочница](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/KYDwDg9gTgLgBMAdgVwLZwMoBUCCWCqGAohgPoByOAsiXAN4BQczcAwgEpF5EAicAvHADkgQhBAfCCB2EEAsIIAYQQLwgYoQBomLHkQAyRLLwHDAxCCzA3CCBWEAXLVzAPRW4gPBBA4iBnAMiBxAPCALAzCBi4gDhA3gIogcnCAgiCAQiAyYYDCICFigEwgDAC%20DAwAZsiIAMYwAJYQiHCkoDkAzjAl5ACGqMAAFIjVwABccGVQOYgA5gCULQBGEBAANsCVBYwscDZwUMAwyFAFAPJ9AFbA2QB0AG6VQ8jAJbXYeIQkFNQk3ZsdmfsAJof1jd0A3JYzcwsFpaQnBMQyJQaBhnjVukkUuksrl8nBfv8zkDLqCGjUWmMAJ69OBo4DwkqYXAA87A2gTFizeaLOArdZbXb7J6IwEXEHXW4PJ54t6QlIwQ4wFoU5jQ7J5AoCspg5qtGDtLrdegfSY5VJwWoI4lItkkGXdJUiybGzL5MpwGAARj0eKmtlNiHNVpaLNJKJVxuYdI2MB2ewOR1dyPZNyyXKOPNedoJtIA0h7mIkEEMSvijZ7mA6nQAmG2NaNZ%20AwbMtNodToJuDJSbJZJAA)

```
export enum STATUSES_NAMES {
    CREATED = 'Создано',
    DELETED = 'Удалено',
    // Очень много имён статусов
}

function _existsName(name: string): boolean {
    // return Object.values(STATUSES_NAMES).includes(name);
    return is_STATUSES_NAMES(name)
}

function is_STATUSES_NAMES(name: any): name is STATUSES_NAMES {
    return Object.values(STATUSES_NAMES).includes(name);
}


test: {
    function test(name: string) {
        if (is_STATUSES_NAMES(name)) {
            const t1 = name // const t1: STATUSES_NAMES
            Object.values(STATUSES_NAMES).includes(name); // is OK
        } else {
            const t2 = name // const t2: string
        }
    }
}
```

### 4

можно ещё придумать вариации на тему:

```
    enum names {
        CREATED = 'Создано',
        DELETED = 'Удалено',
        // Очень много имён статусов
    }
    class Name extends String {
        constructor(name: names) { super(name) }
    }

    function _existsName(name: Name | string): boolean {
        return name instanceof Name
    }
    const _name = new Name(names.CREATED)
    console.log(_name)
    console.log(_existsName(_name))
```

### 5 но правильно будет так

```
    enum names {
        CREATED,
        DELETED,
        // Очень много имён статусов
    }

    function ch(name: names | string): boolean {
        return name in names
    }
    console.log(ch(names.CREATED))
    console.log(ch('CREATED'))
```

---

сравнение:

```
namespace A {
    enum names {
        CREATED = 'Создано',
        DELETED = 'Удалено',
    }
}
namespace B {
    enum names {
        CREATED,
        DELETED,
    }
}
```

```
var A;
(function (A) {
    let names;
    (function (names) {
        names["CREATED"] = "\u0421\u043E\u0437\u0434\u0430\u043D\u043E";
        names["DELETED"] = "\u0423\u0434\u0430\u043B\u0435\u043D\u043E";
    })(names || (names = {}));
})(A || (A = {}));
var B;
(function (B) {
    let names;
    (function (names) {
        names[names["CREATED"] = 0] = "CREATED";
        names[names["DELETED"] = 1] = "DELETED";
    })(names || (names = {}));
})(B || (B = {}));
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. 1  - я принципиально не испльзую `// @ts-ignore`. 2. У меня много статусов и данный вариант не кажется мне хорошим решением. 3. Мне не нравится `: any`. А где можно прочитать про: `: name is STATUSES_NAMES`? Это аналог `as`?

Comment: "А где можно прочитать про" - где-то в доках в описании одного из релизов

Comment: расширил ответ, см пункт 5

Comment: [https://www.google.com/?q=typescript is operator](https://www.google.com/?q=typescript%20is%20operator) -> [typeof-type-guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#typeof-type-guards)

Comment: Я не понимаю в чём смысл сгенерированного кода, кроме того, что значения будут под разными ключами. Поясните 5 пример)

Comment: этот код - это то, как работает TS ... то во что он компилирует

Comment: Понятнее не стало, в чём соль?)

Comment: то во что он компилирует. просто он так работает. и никакие извращения не нужны с проверками

Comment: наверное, это поведение можно сравнить с `Symbol` из JS

Comment: или `enum` нужен не как ключи а как словарь?

Comment: [немного магии для словарей](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?allowUnusedLabels=true#code/MYewdgzgLgBGCGBbAphGBeGBvAsAKBhgGEAlAUQEEAVMgEQC4YByQQhBA+EEHYQQFhBAGEEF4QNkwA0+QrTIAZMjQbNAxCC9A3CCBWEAHDRMAPSaYgPBBA4iCrAMiAxAPCADAzCBsYgDhBTgRRA+MQIIggIRAerwMIgztoCYQfAC+MPBooJBQANz4+FAAngAOyHBIqBgwcYkgAGbJKBAxCUkIeQD6ANbIsWiYFbHZuagFiQ0QJQBu8AA21S0A2sWo5ZUQALrReFkArmDAUACW4DAlyAAec9AQAHIpABQDjAOtHd0wAD4w0ABOc2AA5gCUjABGICCdyPBg2Bph0DCd61gmAA8k8AFbIWYAOmOk1QexSEHuwTQVxut16YwIMEuyCgk0uXwB0ChN2AnUmABN4QN7lE8AF8EA) - `as const`

Comment: а ещё лучше `const names = Object.freeze({
  CREATED: 'Создано',
  DELETED: 'Удалено',
} as const)`

Comment: как вариант, вместо `as const` - `{[k:string]:string}`

Comment: Да. Как словарь. Вот я такого ожидал  `Object.freeze({   CREATED: 'Создано',   DELETED: 'Удалено', } as const)`  `enum`. +1 за ответ.

Comment: Ну и в том варианте значения `enum` никак не изменить из вне.

Answer (score 0):

Убираем ошибку можно добавив ассоциацию с `enum`:

```js
private static _existsName(name: string): boolean {
  return Object.values(STATUSES_NAMES).includes(name as STATUSES_NAMES);
}
```

Похожий вопрос: [https://stackoverflow.com/](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43804805/check-if-value-exists-in-enum-in-typescript).

***P.S.*** *Решения, которое больше похоже на костыль, но других и лучше вариантов не нашел.*